# Batch Increment in Hbase

Tags: java, hbase

When I try to do batch increment on hbase table (without rowkey duplicates)

```
 final List<Increment> increments = countPerUid.entrySet().stream()
                .map(entry -> {
                    Increment increment = new Increment(toBytes(entry.getKey()));
                    increment.addColumn(toBytes(conf.parentColumnFamily()), toBytes(conf.parentRankQualifier()), entry.getValue());
                    return increment;
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());

 public BatchOperationResult batchIncrement(HTable table, List<Increment> rows) {
        Object[] results = new Object[rows.size()];
        try {
            table.batch(rows, results);
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            Throwables.propagate(e);
        }
        return new BatchOperationResult(results);
    }
```

I have got such exception:

```
    2015-05-13 09:53:43,674 [Thread-9] ERROR hbase_query_layer.service.HbaseLayerServiceHandlerImpl - java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException:
 Failed 14896 actions: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.OperationConflictException: The operation with nonce {-3517837563370374612, -1595005354043534544} on row [298270339298463040] may have already completed
```

Someone knows why?:/

I have Hbase 0.98.0

Comment: Value you try to increment is it a Long ? HBase supports increments only on long.

Comment: Can you check if some operations have the same nonce ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a temporary solution, one needs to split increment batch for smaller chunks.

Answer (score 2):

Unrelated, but I thought I'd suggest trying efficient readless increments here, as obviously you are trying to speed up your increments with batching.

Example for HBase 0.98 can be found here: https://github.com/caskdata/cdap-hbase-increments